# Why is usage of javascript within visualvm (jhat?) oql sometimes confusing?

Tags: javascript, visualvm, oql, jhat

I am interested in knowing why visualvm OQL has a problem with the following statement:

```
select filter(heap.objects("java.util.HashMap"), isTrue(it));

function isTrue(object) {  
  return true;  
}
```

Exception is:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "it" is not defined. (#1)
```

In contrast, visualvm OQL does not have a problem with any of the following examples:

Example 1 (note "it" is not quoted):

```
select filter(heap.objects("java.util.HashMap"),  
    function(it) {  
      return true;  
    });
```

Example 2 (note "it" is quoted):

```
select filter(heap.objects("java.util.HashMap"), isTrue("it"));  

function isTrue(object) {  
  if (object instanceof String) {  
    throw "String passed!";  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

Example 3 ("function(it)" handled specially in OQL for some reason?):

```
select filter(heap.objects("java.util.HashMap"), function(it) { return isTrue(it); });

function isTrue(object) {  
  return true;  
}
```

I ask this because it seems non-intuitive and variations of non-intuitive behavior show up unexpectedly and slow me down when I am trying to create something usable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your different syntaxes are *not* equivalent. The first:

```
select filter(heap.objects("java.util.HashMap"), isTrue(it));
```

calls `isTrue` with a parameter of `it` and passes its *result* to the `filter()` function. At that point you don't have a variable `it` defined, hence the error.

Your "example 1" and "example 3" both pass a function as the second parameter to the `filter()` function. The function you pass in is (presumably) intended as a callback that `filter()` will call, where the parameter `it` will be set by `filter()`.

Your "example 2" is a bit like the first code in that it calls `isTrue("it")` immediately, but in this case it is calling it with a string literal, so you don't have a problem with the parameter being undefined. However, again this is passing the result of the function as a parameter to `filter()` rather than passing the function itself.

**Correct usage of `filter()`** is to pass it a function (either a function reference - the name of a function *without* parentheses - or a function expression like in your "example 1"). So try the following:

```
select filter(heap.objects("java.util.HashMap"), isTrue);

function isTrue(object) {  
  return true;  
}

// OR your example 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @nnnnnn. I learned several things about JavaScript and OQL from your example and details.

Comment: For example, @nnnnnn, I should have used (typeof object=="string") as my comparator in example #2 (based on your reply I researched why the if statement did not catch the string being passed!). Also, I was building on my flawed examples to create more complicated and flawed statements: filter(array, childOfMyClass("it","referrers(it)")) is an example where childOfMyClass is passed two parameters and I now can see is obviously wrong. I changed it to take one parameter and I pass the filter childOfMyClass without the argument list.